# How can I get the Eclipse version programmatically?

Tags: eclipse

I need to get the Eclipse version programmatically but I've not found a way
to get that version.
Could anyone have a suggestion, please?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of versions in Eclipse, the nearest to what you want is probably the `org.eclipse.platform` version. So try

```
Version version = Platform.getBundle("org.eclipse.platform").getVersion();
```

Comment: This is broken on Eclipse 4.4 Luna :(

Comment: @Imeron It works fine for me on Luna. If you are running it in a RCP you won't have the org.eclipse.platform plugin and would need to use something else.

Comment: That was the issue. Adding org.eclipse.platform to the Required plug-ins list fixed the problem. I guess before Luna org.eclipse.platform was included as a dependency for some other plug-in I was using.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

```
 org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getBundle("my.feature.id").getHeaders().get("Bundle-Version");
```