# How to know the eclipse version name?

Tags: java, eclipse

I installed the new eclipse Luna.

How I can know in code if the eclipse version  ?(Luna or Kepler ....)
I want to do it in code.I need to add logic in case that the eclipse is Luna

Comment: What do you want to test for? It might be better to check the version of the appropriate plugins

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the Eclipse version programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20652614/how-can-i-get-the-eclipse-version-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an Eclipse plugin you can get information about the product using:

```
IProduct product = Platform.getProduct();
```

The about dialog text is obtained with:

```
String aboutText = product.getProperty(IProductConstants.ABOUT_TEXT);
```

I don't think there is anything that just gives you the Eclipse version (4.4) or name (Luna).

Often it is better to check the version of a particular plugin, for example:

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("org.eclipse.platform");

Version version = bundle.getVersion();

if (version.getMajor() == 4 && version.getMinor() == 4)
 {
   ... version 4.4
 }
```

Comment: Platform.getPlatform() didn't exist

Comment: Sorry - getProduct();

Answer (score 0):

In the menu bar GO to Help > About Eclipse.

Ex. -

```
Version: Indigo Service Release 1
Build id: 20110916-0149
```

Comment: I want to do it in code.I need to add logic in case that the eclipse is Luna

Comment: Eclipse is in your development environment. Why do you need this in the production environment ?

Comment: yes but I have problem in my build.so i need to know if to add logic in vase that the eclipse is luna

Comment: I think it is not possible directly in Java, instead you can keep a property in a property file, and mention the eclipse version in that. and read it programatically or using Ant in case of building.